# You need to upgrade your less-loader version to 7 or highernnnvbvbv

Tags: less, less-loader

I solved this problem by upgrading the version of "less" and "less-loader" to above 7. I started looking for the answer to this problem for a long time, but could not find it. Then I tried to upgrade "less-loader", which also solved this problem. And in the later version less-loader configures